# UIButton сверху  Scroll

Tags: xcode, objective-c

Добрый день. Возникла трудность. Есть кнопка, которая находиться в низу экрана (статическая) и скролл, который должен быть под ней.

Но вот этот скролл скрывает мою кнопку. Через Xib кнопка выше, даже пытался ее кодом заставить отобразиться над скроллом, но безуспешно. Кто-то может подсказать как мне поднять кнопку над скроллом ?

Comment: Два вопроса: 1) каким кодом пытались заставить отобразиться над скроллом? 2) Ваши кнопка и скролл оба имеют одного view-родителя или разных?

Comment: 1) Попытка банальна, просто хард кодом в DidLoad после добавления скрола на View добавил кнопку
2) Scroll и Button  на одной и той же View

Comment: Я добавил ответ. Если это вам не помогает, добавьте ссылку на свой zip-проект в вопрос по образцу http://hashcode.ru/questions/217638/ios-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5 - будем разбираться.

Comment: Подправил ответ.

Comment: Ещё, подравьте заголовок своего вопроса - UIButton (с двумя t)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще-то, это должно делаться прямо в вашем xib'е:

В панельке Objects вашего Xib'а - у вас представлена иерархия: View, который содержит UIScrollView и Button. Вы можете просто передвигать один или другой - этого должно быть достаточно, чтобы изменить порядок "кто над кем".

Если же вам понадобятся более сложные механизмы определения z-index'ов элементов, см. соответствующие методы UIView:

```
Managing the View Hierarchy

    superview  property
    subviews  property
    window  property
    – addSubview:
    – bringSubviewToFront:
    – sendSubviewToBack:
    – removeFromSuperview
    – insertSubview:atIndex:
    – insertSubview:aboveSubview:
    – insertSubview:belowSubview:
    – exchangeSubviewAtIndex:withSubviewAtIndex:
    – isDescendantOfView:
```

?

То есть тогда, наверное, самым простым способом будет написать в viewDidLoad:

```
[yourView bringSubviewToFront:yourButton];
```

Чтобы поднять кнопку на самый верх. *yourView* - это тот самый родитель обоих кнопки и скролла, в вашем случае это может быть self.view, то есть view вашего контроллера.

Comment: Я отредактировал ответ ещё раз. Возможно вам достаточно просто перетащить соответствующий элемент наверх прямо в вашем xib'е, без какого-либо кода!